# Cloud based spam filter I can forward mail through

Tags: email, spam, saas

**Situation**

We have a cloud ticketing system (think Zendesk) which is currently being overrun with spam. The ticketing system vendor has some anti-spam features but they're not doing a good enough job.

We use Google Apps for email on our domain and we have a Google Apps routing rule that forwards our support email to our ticketing system email.

Ie: support@ourcompany.com -> ourcompany@ticketingsystem.com

**What I'm looking for**

I'm hoping to find a SaaS spam filter that allows me to forward email via them.

Something like: support@ourcompany.com -> ourcompany@spamfilter.com -> ourcompany@ticketingsystem.com

Obviously only emails which pass the spam filter would get forwarded to ourcompany@ticketingsystem.com.

Bonus features:

- The ability to send daily reports that can be checked manually for false positives
- The ability to white-list a large set of domains. 90% of the people submitting tickets will be using domains belonging to our customers and I have most of their domains on file

I've considered simply creating a Google Apps inbox and forwarding it via that (as oppose to using just a routing rule), as we get most of the same spam to our personal inbox's but Google Apps filters it almost perfectly. This wouldn't have a daily spam report feature though which would be really good.

Most cloud spam filters I've seen require you to point your MX records for your whole domain at them, but I don't really want to do this as then I'd have to pay for every inbox we have and none of the inbox's on Google Apps have a spam problem. Creating a dedicated sub-domain and email account eg. spam@spamfilter.mycompany.com might be a way around this, but I'd prefer something simpler if it exists.